# Dropdown won't get on top of Flash in IE7

Tags: flash, object, internet-explorer-7, drop-down-menu

My problem is, that i have a flash banner, with a menu above it. The menu has a dropdown though, and in internet explorer 7 the dropdown shows behind the flash banner. 
I've tried everything (what I know of, and what I have found here on stackoverflow), but nothing seems to do the trick.

Here is a [**link**](http://www.ecovag.com/Home-155.aspx) 
You can find the problem up in the right corner, if you hover over "Select Country: ...".

I've tried to change the wmode to transparent and opaque, but it didn't work. Just to make sure, I did this by adding a `<param value="transparent" name="wmode">` in the `object tag`, and then add the attribute `wmode="transparent"`.

Comment: Yeah... And I just tried it once more. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simple: I simply had to remove `position: relative` and `z-index` from the flash elements container (the `div tag` containing my flash object) :)